# Can I load (usually referenced) dll at runtime without knowing the path?

Tags: c#, dll, runtime

Can I load `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (more or less) like I can do with excel ? I don't want to reference the dll in my project but to load it at runtime.

**How to load any Framework dll ?**

- `Assembly.LoadFile(...);` ?
- but then I need to get the path of it. How ?

---

Excel example:

```
dynamic excel = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"));
```

I wished I could then use dynamic objects like that:

```
PrincipalContext context1 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); // referenced dll
dynamic context2 = ???; // loaded at runtime
```

Comment: Why don't you want to make a compile-time reference to a .dll that you know at compile-time you need a reference to.

Comment: @KirkWoll Right now I'm writing a dll that will contain the dynamically loaded reference to the dll and I want **my** dll being usable without having to reference all dlls it would reference statically.

Comment: Still seems easier to just load them statically, but I'm sure you have your reasons.  Are the other dlls in the same location as your application's assemblies?  Do you just need to get the path to one of those?

Comment: @KirkWoll No. My execution directory contains only my dll and my exe.

Answer (score 0):

Referenced dlls/assemblies are probably built to the folder where your exe file in. You can load them from there(using Sytem.AppDomain.Current.BaseDirectory to get the path). There's no such a way as your demand to load assembly without specified path or you can implement it as what you have descriped